# Accessing a file from Latex using hyperref command without closing the original file

Tags: external-files

In my beamer presentation, I'm using hyperref package, and `\href` command to open a pdf file. The problem is that the presentation seems to be substituted/closed by the openning of that new file. Is there a way to correct it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `pdfnewwindow`, e.g. `\href[pdfnewwindow]{URL}{text}`.

If all external file links should result in an new window, you can set the option also at `\usepackage` or `\hypersetup`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. By the way, how would I set that option for all links?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. ??? See the already existing second sentence of my answer. See also the explanation of the option and `\hypersetup` in the `hyperref` manual.